# Load balancer for Web Services Provider

Tags: linux, tomcat, load, debian

I have a Web Services provider (deployed in Tomcat 6). The web service provider is expected to receive a huge amount of requests so, I’d like to know what is –in your opinion and experience- the best way to balance loads? (the question assumes that if one Tomcat is not enough, another one will be added to the solution and thus the need for a load balancer).

Just in case you need to know, the Server runs Linux Debian (last stable).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "huge" if you can - request per hour or day would be helpful. Will the requests be for static resources (images, html, css, js) or dynamic URIs (servlets, applications)?

Comment: Certainly welcome to ask here but you might get a better response at webmasters.stackexchange.com.  I've voted to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a serverfault question, but use a hardware load balancer of if this is a low-budget situation nginx might work too, e.g.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule